# How to change latexmk's number of maximum runs

Tags: latexmk

I'm compiling my .tex file using `latexmk`, because it's the easiest way to have my code compiled multiple times until the final document is stable.

The issue is that such code needs to be executed several times - actually, a *random* amount of times - because it uses several images that tend to appear in the wrong position unless the code gets executed again and again and again until the following warning goes away from the log:

> LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

The point is that after several times that the code gets compiled I receive this message in the terminal:

> Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'generatore dossier.tex':
>      'pdflatex' needed too many passes

Is there a way to change the maximum amount of runs that `latexmk` does before calling it quits?

Comment: Yes, there is a command-line parameter to do that - but I can't remember what it is, and I don't feel like reading the documentation when you can do that yourself!

Comment: there are some situations where the changing of labels is pathological.  this might be helpful in understanding that situation: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105612/579

Comment: You will probably save time by including some more specific "hints" about where to position things in the document - for example specify "top of next page" to a figure which keeps moving around, or add an explicit `\linebreak` or `\pagebreak` to keep footnotes from flipping between one page and the next.

Comment: That issue can be discussed here
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359772/background-in-wrong-position-with-heavy-files/360317#360317

Answer (score 14):

You can change the `$max_repeat` variable with a command line option or in a configuration file.

```
latexmk -e "$max_repeat=2" test
```

or perhaps on other OS/shells with a single quote

```
latexmk -e '$max_repeat=2' test
```

But the default value (5) is quite large, so you should at first try to find out why your document needs more.

Comment: this is strange btw because even if I change the initialization document OR I use that command I end up receiving this message after 2 runs: `Latexmk: Maximum runs of pdflatex reached without getting stable files
Latexmk: All targets (generatore dossier.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'generatore dossier.tex':
   'pdflatex' needed too many passes`

Comment: My example set the number of run to 2 and this is a rather small value. If you want a larger value use e.g. 10.

Comment: That's what I did in fact

Comment: Is there a way to pass this as a `!TEX parameter =` in eg. TeXShop?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer while 5 is fine for many use cases there are definitely legitimate cases where it is way larger, e.g. when `latexmk` is used to generate PDF versions of images from `*.svg` in conjunction with `make` it requires one `pdflatex` run per generated image (because `make` gets aware of the required `*.pdf` only after `pdflatex` encounters the respective failing `\includegraphics` command and writes it out as dependency. I'll probably post a question about it in the future but not time yet for a MWE. :)

Comment: My problem was an artifact of using `-halt-on-error` (which I think is favorable to ease debugging). Using `-interaction=nonstopmode` fixes that problem and generates all missing images after a single (eventually failing) run.

Comment: Latexmk: Stopping because executing following code from command line
    =2
gave an error:
    syntax error at (eval 7) line 1, near "="

Answer (score 4):

See also from the man page:

```
       $max_repeat [5]
              The  maximum  number  of  times  latexmk will run latex/pdflatex
              before deciding that there may be an infinite loop and  that  it
              needs to bail out, rather than rerunning latex/pdflatex again to
              resolve cross-references, etc.  The  default  value  covers  all
              normal cases.

              (Note  that  the  "etc"  covers  a lot of cases where one run of
              latex/pdflatex generates files to be read in on a later run.)
```

Source: `man latexmk`, also [available online on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf) or from `texdoc latexmk`.