# Insert cover as a png on entire page of a document

Tags: templates, overleaf, png

I am using a template on overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/d-and-d-5e-latex-template/vmfdkjfhfynv) and I wrote the entire document. I had created a png file, with the same size of a page, to put on the cover, but I can't.

The picture is inserted within the page a yet consider the margin, so the image stand dislocated from the upper left corner. I had created a .pdf with the image but the same problem appears. For those examples I used *changepage*, *pdfpages* packages and I wrote within the environment *titlepage*.

I couldn't find any other question that assembles with this one. I want to put a png file into the first page of the document ignoring margins and other things that this template automatically puts on the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you looked at [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167719/110998)?

Comment: Or [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46280/how-to-create-a-background-image-on-title-page-with-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46280/110998)?

Comment: Or [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368132/set-background-image-without-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368132/110998)?

Comment: Thank you @gernot. The first one works.
I didn't know how to search for this kind of problem.

Comment: I googled for `latex adding background image`.

Comment: Because I do not want to be in the background. The image has to be on the front, not in the background. But it worked.